# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LeadStatus'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am trying to run the following Stored procedure in sql server and its giving the below error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LeadStatus'.

The stored proc is just updating the field 'RecQuality' based on value in 'LeadStatus' column..RecQuality is an integer field .find the stored procedure below

```
   Create Procedure [dbo].[ETL_SetRecordWeightsForLeadStatus]
    @TableName as varchar(50) ,
    @FieldName as varchar(50) 

As
Begin


    Declare @Sql nvarchar(500);



        SET @Sql = 'Update [dbo].[' + @TableName + '] 
                    Set RecQuality = Case When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-1'' Then  RecQuality +100
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-2'' Then  RecQuality +90
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-3'' Then  RecQuality +80
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-4'' Then  RecQuality +70
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-5'' Then  RecQuality +60
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-6'' Then  RecQuality +50
                                          When [' + @FieldName + '] = ''Tier-0'' Then  RecQuality +40
                                          Else  RecQuality +0 End 
                     Where LEN([' + @FieldName + ']) > 0 ';





    Execute sp_executesql @Sql;

End
```

When i am running the Sql as below individually replacing parameters with values its running fine.

```
Update [dbo].[CannonListTest_WithStatus_deduped1] 
                Set RecQuality = Case When LeadStatus = 'Tier-1' Then  RecQuality +100
                                      When LeadStatus= 'Tier-2' Then  RecQuality +90
                                      When LeadStatus = 'Tier-3' Then  RecQuality +80
                                      When LeadStatus = 'Tier-4' Then  RecQuality +70
                                      When LeadStatus = 'Tier-5' Then  RecQuality +60
                                      When LeadStatus = 'Tier-6' Then  RecQuality +50
                                      When LeadStatus = 'Tier-0' Then  RecQuality +40
                                      Else  RecQuality +0 End 
                 Where LEN(LeadStatus) > 0
```

I am unable to find exactly where the issue is.Can some one help me with the error?

Comment: Put `PRINT @Sql` inside your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The `nvarchar` variable used to store the query (`@Sql`) is not big enough for the query you use. So change

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(500);
```

to

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max);
```